# How to rewrite response.json() for xml response?

Tags: python, json, xml, python-requests

I have to request to the page that returns xml format. I suppose to work with data I get, so in case it will be json data, I would write something like

```
if response.content:
    try:
        res_decoded = response.json()
```

But what if I know It is data in format xml, how does this part of code should look?
Just simply confused

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an element tree. Thankfully, python has support for this built in.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html